# Type '[string, (theme: string) => void]' is not assignable to type 'BackgroundColor | undefined'. Trouble typing createContext theme

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

It's written in React + TypeScript
This is my Context file

```js
import { createContext } from "react";

const ThemeContext = createContext<[string, (theme: string) => void]>(
    [
        "green",
        () => {},
    ]
);

export default ThemeContext;
```

and here I tried implementing it

```js
return (
<div> 
  <ThemeContext.Consumer>             `  
    {(theme) => <button 
                  onClick={this.toggleModal} 
                  style={{backgroundColor: theme }}
    >

      Switch Modal
    </button>)}  
  </ThemeContext.Consumer>
</div>  
);
```

After running the code I get an error

```
Type '[string, (theme: string) => void]' is not assignable to type 'BackgroundColor | undefined'.   
Type '[string, (theme: string) => void]' is not assignable to type 'string & {}'.     
Type '[string, (theme: string) => void]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

How do I fix this?
I tried migrating the app to TS, I expected the app to work as it did previously, before migration, it didn't work as intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reference the color itself, which is the first item in the array.
So, instead of `style={{backgroundColor: theme }}`, it should be `style={{backgroundColor: theme[0] }}`

i.e.,

```
return (
<div> 
  <ThemeContext.Consumer>             `  
    {(theme) => <button 
                  onClick={this.toggleModal} 
                  style={{backgroundColor: theme[0] }}
    >

      Switch Modal
    </button>)}  
  </ThemeContext.Consumer>
</div>  
);
```

or

```
return (
<div> 
  <ThemeContext.Consumer>             `  
    {([color]) => <button 
                  onClick={this.toggleModal} 
                  style={{backgroundColor: color }}
    >

      Switch Modal
    </button>)}  
  </ThemeContext.Consumer>
</div>  
);
```